# How to make Selenium chrome web driver fast

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
@Before
public void setUpRestClient() throws InterruptedException {

    try {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<String> indexSuburbStatePost = new ArrayList<String>();

        indexSuburbStatePost.add("ABC");
        indexSuburbStatePost.add("YYZ");

        for (int j = 0; j < indexSuburbStatePost.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println("for loop===>"   + indexSuburbStatePost.get(j));


            mySchoolDriver(indexSuburbStatePost.get(j));

            Thread.sleep(10000);
            List<String> indexNumberSchool = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> indexNameSchool = new ArrayList<String>();

            List<WebElement> elementsAdv = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='SearchResults']/tbody/tr/td"));
            System.out.println("Test advance elements number of elements: " + elementsAdv.size());

            writeToFile(indexSuburbStatePost.get(j));

            for (WebElement eleadv : elementsAdv) {

                System.out.println("Text adv======>" + eleadv.getText());
                if (eleadv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Primary")
                        || eleadv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Secondary")
                        || eleadv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Government")
                        || eleadv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Combined")
                        || eleadv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Special")
                        || eleadv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "Non-government")) {

                } else {
                    indexNameSchool.add(eleadv.getText());
                }

            }

            Iterator<String> indexNumberSchoolIteratorAA = indexNameSchool
                    .iterator();

            for (int k = 0; k < indexNameSchool.size(); k++) {
                System.out.println("indexNumberSchoolIterator AA===>"+ indexNumberSchoolIteratorAA.next());
                writeToFile(indexNameSchool.get(k));

            }
            List<WebElement> elementscss = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#SearchResults tr a"));
            for (WebElement e : elementscss) {
                String url = e.getAttribute("href");
                System.out.println(url.substring(url.length() - 5));
                indexNumberSchool.add(url.substring(url.length() - 5));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < indexNumberSchool.size(); i++) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                writeToFile(indexNumberSchool.get(i));

                try {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/Home/Index/"+ indexNumberSchool.get(i) + "\"]")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.id("IAccept")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.className("captch-submit")).click();
                } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                     do nothing, link is not present, assert is passed 
                    System.out.println(" NoSuchElementException======>" + ex.getMessage());

                    mySchoolDriver(indexSuburbStatePost.get(j));

                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/Home/Index/"+ indexNumberSchool.get(i) + "\"]")).click();
                }
                driver.findElement(By.id("NaplanMenuButton")).click();
                try {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"NaplanMenu\"]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
                } catch (ElementNotVisibleException envex) {
                    System.out.println(" ElementNotVisibleException======>"+ envex.getMessage());
                }

                List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ResultsInNumbersContainer']/table/tbody/tr"));
                System.out.println("Test7 number of elements: " + elements.size());
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                File f = null;
                for (WebElement ele : elements) {
                    if (ele.getAttribute("class").equalsIgnoreCase( "selected-school-row")) {
                            writeToFile(ele.getText());
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        driver.close();
    }

}

private void mySchoolDriver(String indxSuburbPost) {
    driver.get("http://www.abc.xyz.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("SuburbTownPostcodeSearch")).sendKeys(indxSuburbPost);
    driver.findElement(By.id("SuburbTownPostcodeSearchSubmit")).submit();
}

private void writeToFile(String indxSuburbPost) {
    try{


    String filename = "C:/logs/data.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true); 
    fw.write(indxSuburbPost + "\n");
    fw.write("\n");
    fw.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hi Friends,

I have above code and it is working fine and getting the data which I need. My only problem is : it is very slow.
If you look at the code he place where it is very slow is where I am cathing errors:
catch (NoSuchElementException ex) AND
catch (ElementNotVisibleException envex)

it takes ages to error to get caught.Can some one please help.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the `.implicitlyWait()` set at 200s. When an element is being located and not found, it will wait for 200s. My suggestion is to remove the implicit wait (and `Thread.sleep()`s) and replace them with explicit waits using [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [`ExpectedConditions`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(...)).click();

// as long as you are OK with the time setting in the above WebDriverWait declaration
// (10 seconds), you can reuse the wait again and again with the same 10s wait.
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(...));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(...)).click();
```

[Read more](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) about explicit and implicit waits and why you shouldn't mix them.

Comment: what if i remove the whole implicit statement? will it make code crash?

Comment: No, it's not going to make your code crash. It's possible that the code won't run to completion because you are missing waits here and there that will need to be added. It will go much, much faster though...

Comment: if i am not wrong every time i call driver.findElements this implicit wait gets called.?
if that is the case then do i need to put that piece of code before every find Element call?

Comment: You should take a look at [the docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits), it will explain more but yes... setting the implicit wait is for the life of the driver instance so it only needs to be called once. The explicit waits that I am referring to in my answer need to be called for each instance you need to wait. If you want to wait 10s for each element, then you can reuse the `wait` I declared in the code above each time.